# Segmentation Error (core dumped) when trying to print %s

Tags: c

I'm following a course at https://www.root-me.org/fr/Documentation/Applicatif/Chaine-de-format-lecture-en-memoire

This is my code:

```
char comment[200];
printf("Test string");
scanf("%s",comment);
printf(comment);
```

And when I enter the comment, which is "%s", it gives a segmentation error.

According to the course, it should print "Test string".

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where you found it in your course (I did not find it in the link you provide, i speak french)

Comment: Voici le lien :https://www.root-me.org/fr/Documentation/Applicatif/Chaine-de-format-introduction
Le code n'est exactement comme ça

Comment: Quand il demande d'entrer comment,  je tape %s

Comment: @m2cky My french is bad, but it seems that this tutorial demonstrates the security vulnerability generated by using a user-supplied string as the first argument to `printf` as in `printf(comment);`. Whether this vulnerability will actually work depends on your compiler and its settings. The segmentation dump indicates that it didn't work. Also try something like `%.10s` to avoid `printf` running of the stack if there is no zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are writing "%s" in the standard input.

```
 comment is "%s"
 printf(comment) is printf("%s")
```

This will result in a segfault 99% of the time. Because you are using %s without a valid C-string in your printf argument.

Compare to this version that should work: instead of printf(comment), use printf(comment, "some text")

```
 comment is "%s"
 printf(comment, "some text") is printf("%s", "some text")
```

You are passing a string with a conversion flag that cannot be interpreted correctly. Your input is unsafe.